# MVC = Classic ASP With Separation = ASP.NET Web Forms in tiered architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I'm new to MVC and am partly my way through a course and am trying to understand a few things. Firstly, it looks and works like classic ASP, but with a but more functionality. 15 years ago, it was frowned upon to mix code and HTML, but thats what MVC does now.

Also, the separation of logic is great, but you can do this in a tiered n-level model architecture in normal ASP.NET web-forms. Sure MVC forces you to do it, but the same can be done via the latter. No control over the HTML, .NET 4.5 you can turn off viewstate and control the Id's better. You can also use boostrap, ninject, jquery, ORM's in standard ASP.NET web-forms. And is a litle viewstate so bad when ADSL speeds are so high nowadays.

With unit testing, if you have correct separation in your web-form model, this can be done as well can't it? Not that any commercial company i've been have given any time to writing unit-tests...its mostly left out...i know this isn't perfect, but hey it's the real world.

I've read that for the initial extra work MVC means it's easier to add to a application...however, isn't that true for a web-forms app that's been designed well?

The extra code you have to write in MVC seems so much more effort than dragging controls onto a form and hooking them up. It seems like having a nice ORM and going back to old style ADO, just because it gives you "more control".

Can someone answer what MVC does that you can't do in a properly structured web-forms project???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely complex question, but it is good that you asked it.

I would recommend that you spend sometime studying design patterns and the inner workings of Classic ASP, Web Forms, and Microsoft MVC.  They are by no means equivalent, and the underlying functionality is entirely different.

That being said, I will address a couple of the specific things you asked about.

You cannot cleanly separate the logic and create a true n-tiered loosely coupled application in Web Forms.  The way the form controls work is that the server embeds a lot of functionality into the web page before it is sent to the client.  This creates a hard dependency between the client tier and the server tier.

It is somewhat of a myth that you have to write more code with MVC than with Web Forms.  I generally write less code with MVC than I do with Web Forms.  MVC takes care of a lot of things through the design pattern than does not happen in Web Forms.  The first one that jumps out when you use MVC for a short time is the strongly typed models.  This makes it much easier to map data to the views and construct forms.  Add on top the validation goodness that you can get using data annotations and MVC model validation, and you will write a lot less code.

Dragging controls onto a form and hooking them up results in a lot of code being generated for you. Since that code is very generic and not compile time checked, it tends to be very cumbersome and prone to very hard to find bugs.  Further, much of what you do on the form in Web Forms is not compile time checked, so things like ObjectDataSource that are late bound at run time can fail due to something like an unavailable database, and there is nothing that you can do to prevent the error from hitting the client.  In MVC, you can catch the database error before it leaves the server and have a much more elegant and efficient response to that error.

I would recommend that you take some time to use browser debugging tools to watch how the different technologies process requests, and take some time to inspect the rendered page markup to see what is really happening.  It is very informative.

It would also benefit you to work through some MVC examples and see the difference between how the code is written compared to Web Forms.  It is a night and day difference.  They are completely different approaches to application construction.

I hope that this has been helpful and will give you some guidance on further investigation.  It really is important for a developer to understand the nuances of these technologies and design patterns to really be able to reach the next level in software development.

Answer (score 0):

i'll definitely take on your advice. Regards a couple of points...you mention;

"strongly typed models", surely you can do this in web-forms with EF-code-first???

Ditto "validation goodness that you can get using data annotations"...we can have the same concept in web-forms EF-code-first although it needs a bit more code.

Also, if you use ninject in web-forms (it's not solely a tool for MVC), then does this not remove the "hard dependency between the client tier and the server tier"???

With .NET 4.5, if you turn off viewstate then you have *nearly* as much control over the markup than MVC right? Especially if you use controls like the repeater in which you have greater flexability?

I totally agree that "They are completely different approaches to application construction."...:)

Also, like web-forms, MVC has a separate project type for the test methods. Hence, like web-forms, it's going to have the same issues, i.e. time-constraints mean that no tests are going to be written in a commercial (real) environment. You can eaily write a MVC application with no unit-tests, hence in the real-world this is going to happen. And unit-testing is one of the primary reasons for using MVC.

I'm just wondering why some people are saying "MVC is the better way", "Web-forms is the wrong way". "Better" in what way that you **can't** do in web-forms? In reality IMHO its just another technology that lets you build apps...one is no better than the other...and like any new technology, you have bandwagon programmers who take it as gospel and bash anything else.